# Is it possible to set the JAVA_HOME env in El Captitan?

Tags: command-line, java, environment-variables

I am unable to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable osx. I added the following line to my `.bash_profile`

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
```

and sourced it afterwards; yet when I printenv or attempt to echo it, I see nothing in Terminal.

Comment: Does setting other variables in `.bashrc` work as expected? Does running `/usr/libexec/java_home` work?

Comment: Did you start a new shell?

Comment: Running /usr/libexec/java_home worked.
It also turns out that setting the environment variable in this file (.bashrc) works but not in the .bash_profile.
I didn't have the .bashrc file in my home folder so I guess this has to be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I got this to work was by setting this environment variable in the `.bashrc` file, which incidentally, isn't created in the users home directory by default.
Thanks to patrix's comments on my question which led to this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the backticks (`) and do something like:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/libexec/java_home"
```